# WP_Query и sub-fields в повторителе ACF

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Использую плагин ACF. Нужно вывести внутри записи произвольного типа `sim` все записи произвольного типа `gv` в которых через `Post Object` (с ключом `mnn_sim`) указана текущая запись (`sim`). Сам `Post Object` находиться в повторителе с ключом `forma_preparata`. При помощи гугла получился такой результат, но он не работает.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'gv',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'forma_preparata_%_mnn_sim',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value'   => get_the_ID(),
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/forum/general-issues/ с таким лучше сюда

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй что то типа такого:

```
array(
    'post_type' => 'gv',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'forma_preparata_mnn_sim',
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
  )
```